# Angular JS ng-view is not working throwing error "cannot get /view_name "

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm working on angular routing configuration and my layout is defined and my partial views are defined in the same folder but on clicking my anchor link, I'm  getting an error

> cannot GET/ view_name

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-
beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
</head>
<body ng-app="myFirstApp">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">
(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/students">Students</a>
            </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/Staff">Staff</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
    <div class="starter-template">
        <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
        <ng-view></ng-view>
    </div>

</div>
<!-- /.container -->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="scripts.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

here is my scripts.js code

```
var app = angular.module('myFirstApp',["ngRoute"]);
app.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider) {
debugger;
$routeProvider
.when('/Staff', {
    templateUrl : 'Staff.html',
})
.when("/students", {
    templateUrl : "students.html",
}
     );
}]);
```

my folder structure is like this

[image]

Comment: consider adding a hash-bang: `href="#!/students` (for angularjs 1.6)

Comment: href="/students" this is wrong...you have to give href="#students" (for angular 1.5)

Comment: @AlekseySolovey in angularjs 1.6 also href="#!students"

Comment: @sudhakar I got it thanks for that, but early I did try the same way but I didn't get the result as expected but now I got it right making the change to href="#!students".

Comment: @AlekseySolovey I did try your way but dint the result.

Comment: @kishore consider this example: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/oK06tzi2S7pRBtfgNuBP?p=preview). Make sure your html templates are named correctly. Your `Staff..html` should be `Staff.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are using AngularJS v1.6.x

Change `href` attribute to:

```
href="#!/students"
```